# Postgresql how can I sum(values) and group them by the month within jsonb?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

**Postgres Query:**

```
SELECT
  ((data->>'date')) AS time,
  ((data->>'totalAmount')) as values
FROM invoices
```

**Output:**

| id | date | total amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-16 | 13 |
| 2 | 2021-01-12 | 52 |
| 3 | 2020-12-17 | 11 |
| 4 | 2020-12-08 | 3 |

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE invoices (
    id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    data jsonb NOT NULL
);
```

What I try to achieve sum(values) by month:

| id | date | total amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01 | 65 |
| 2 | 2020-12 | 14 |

I know that postgres offers:

- extract month
- date_trunc

It seems not to work with jsonb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the text value to a `date` then you can e.g. use `to_char()` to get just the month from it:

```
select to_char((data->>'date')::date, 'yyyy-mm') AS month,
       sum((data->>'totalAmount')::int) as values
from invoices
group by to_char((data->>'date')::date, 'yyyy-mm')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That was exactly what i was searching for !